# Styling horizontal rules

Tags: html, css

Is there a nicer way of styling a `<hr />` tag using CSS, that is cross-browser consistent and doesn't involve wrapping a `div` around it? I'm struggling to find one.

The best way I have found, is as follows:

**CSS**

```
.hr {  
    height:20px;  
    background: #fff url(nice-image.gif) no-repeat scroll center;  
}  
hr {  
    display:none;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hr"><hr /></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic way of doing this is creating a wrapper around the <hr> and styling that. But I have come up a CSS trick for image replacing the element without the need for extra markup:

For non MSIE browsers:

```
hr {
   border : 0;
   height : 15px;
   background : url(hr.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
   margin : 1em 0;
 }
```

Additionally for MSIE:

```
hr {
   display : list-item;
   list-style : url(hr.gif) inside;
   filter : alpha(opacity=0);
   width : 0;
}
```

See [entry on my blog](http://borgar.undraland.com/s/2007/01/style-hr-elements/) for further info and an example of the trick in action.

Comment: This is great, +10 if I could!

Answer (score 1):

If you set display to `block` it should behave more like a `<div>`.

Your answer you should remove hr altogether and just use the `div`

Comment: i disagree. a horizontal rule, though ostensibly a visual element, still carries semantic meaning, whereas a div does not.

Comment: i tend to agree with nickf on that, its in the content for a reason. However setting it to display block may be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the background image to the bottom of the preceding element, perhaps with a bit of extra padding. That way you can get rid of any surplus / non-semantic markup.